# Reading .vtu file in my own program

Tags: c++, visualization, vtk

I'm fairly new to the VTK(visualization toolkit) and came across the unstructured grid file format which might fit my needs in my own project.  I have a bunch of .vtu files that I want to read in my own program and create a mesh out of it.  My question is, how can I read such a file?

- Should I use VTK's file reading capabilities and write an importer? For this I would have integrate VTK into my project/build system.
- Can I write my own C++ based file reader using one of the opensource XML parsers?

Which one is the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: VTK is a very big, so if you are only using the reader, I would not suggest doing so. You can find the source code of the reader online, so maybe you can shadow it and write your own reader.

Answer (score 1):

VTK is great for reading .vtu and other formats [Here it's an example fot .vtu files](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ReadUnstructuredGrid) you should try VTK, once you got it it will save you a lot of time